# Filter [Me] doesn't work correct

Tags: 2010, filter

We have a task list with a filtered view for the users. The filter is  `"assigned to = [me]".`

Normally it works fine, but now there is one users who doesn't see all of his tasks. So i checked the filter and entered instead of [me] his name. I see all of his assigned to tasks. So I think the filter works fine.

There is only one user profile for this user, so this can't be the problem. 
But why he doesn't see all of his taks in the filtered view ([me])? Has anybody an idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you happen to have the "Account operates as system" box checked for this user over on Central Admin?

Comment: what permission this user has? also try from different pc

Comment: The permission-level is contribute. It worked all the time, but suddenly some task are missing. It's frustrating to search for a solution, when you don't know why it happened.